# Webpack. Different rules for different entry points with similar test-mask

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

We have a project with old-good-smarty-part and react-part.

We bundle react-part files with webpack.

We want to bundle non-react-part files with webpack too, but this files are a bit upper than webpack in project-tree. And here is a problem: we need to bundle them and place result to grand-grand-parent directory... So, how to split rules for this entry-point?

```
const ExtractJS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "../../[name].min.js"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    reactApp: ["./src/entries/reactApp/index.tsx"],
    // JS -- we need to place it "upper" than webpack directory in project
    "scripts/oldStuff": ["./src/entries/oldStuff/index.js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: [["es2015", { modules: false }], "stage-2", "react"],
          plugins: ["transform-node-env-inline"],
          env: {
            development: {
              plugins: ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
            },
            targets: {
              browsers: ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 10"]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        include: [/(.*?)scripts(.*?)/, /(.*?)lib(.*?)/],
        use: ExtractJS.extract({
          use: {
            loader: "raw-loader"
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

was tryed to solve this with `include` and `exclude` options, but this looks not good -- we got "cross-entry" files (something like `/lib/foo/bar.js` for react part and `/lib/foo/boar.js` for non-react part) and its about 15-20 files...

And here is a main question: is it possible to exclude entry-point for one rule and include it for another one (with exception of other entry-points)?